# C Explicit syscall()

Tags: c, posix, system-calls

How can I rewrite the program below using `syscall()` function to do the system calls myself instead of using built-in `printf`? (I am interested in Linux, if that makes any difference.)

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("Hello World");

}
```

Comment: You can `write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Hello World", strlen("Hello World"));`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As for your problem, start by tracing to see what system calls are actually made in your program, then learn the `syscall` interface and how to use it. And *experiment*.

Comment: @EOF thx, but `write` is built-in function as well, but I want to execute the system call directly.

Comment: `syscall(SYS_write, STDOUT_FILENO, "Hello World", strlen("Hello World"));` should work, but portability will be much worse.

Comment: `printf` is not a system call.  If you use `syscall` to call something here, it's going to have to be `write`.  (Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, it might be sufficient to use `sprintf` to format your string, then `syscall` to write it.)